# Easy way to download html from a view source while preserving folder structure?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing, web-crawler

I want to convert the html I get from clicking on "view source" into a set of folders with the right html/js/css files and folder hierarchy.

What is a simple way to do this? Are there any existing solutions or libraries that make this any easier than using a crawler and implementing all the parsing and logic from scratch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page in Google Chrome, click CTRL+S and in the save dialog, select "Web Page, Complete"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, you can use this app http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html

And for PC http://www.httrack.com/